# Why does the table look like this?

Tags: oracle

[In sql cmd line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cYK2.png)

[The table(how i want it to look like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxS23.png)

Comment: You can copy the text from console and paste it in code block or `<pre>` tag to keep the original formatting with no need to embed pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set linesize 200
```

is what you're missing. Run it before running the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: But it still will be blank padded to column length (though I think it is good and clear to identify the value, but OP's picture shows values unaligned)